# Intel xolo x900 mobile getting shutdown

Tags: mobile-data

I have trouble with my intel xolo x900 mobile, whenever I have enabled internet unable to use any app , suddenly my mobile getting switched off. It will take nearly 5 min to get back to normal. Not only facing while enabled data but if I'm making calls more times in short duration again same issue.

Interestingly issue not happening mobile while in charging, help me to get this fixed

Thanks,
Asai

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your phone is defective. You should return it to the shop for repair or replacement.

Comment: thanks, I have taken my mobile to three different service centres and I got different response from all three service centres... one said mobile board issue, one said mobile software issue and one said battery issue, useless answers from xolo care.